# Retain Listview values in Base Adapter Class While Scrolling

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION PLEASE READ IT COMPLETLY I HAVE SEARCHED ALL PREVIOUS QUESTION BUT DID NOT FOUND ANY SUITABLE ANSWER.

i am trying to retain Edittext Values in Listview, which is populated using a baseadapter class.

```
public class ServicesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
LayoutInflater vi;

Context context;
ArrayList<ServiceListItems> contactList;
int qty,prc;
public int totalpricestr;
ServiceListItems contactListItems;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;
String ab;



private static final String LIST_STATE = "listState";
private Parcelable mListState = null;

public static final String MY_ORDER_LIST = "orderlist_retrive";

public ServicesListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ServiceListItems> list) {
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    contactList = list;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return contactList.get(position);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 500;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
     contactListItems = contactList.get(position);


    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.services_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.idtxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idtxt);
        holder.service = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.producttxt);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pricetxt);
        holder.editquantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editquantity);

        holder.plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plusbtn);
        holder.minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusbtn);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    String a = String.valueOf(contactListItems.getDbname()!=null);


        holder.idtxt.setText(String.valueOf(contactListItems.getDbid()));
        holder.service.setText(String.valueOf(contactListItems.getDbname()));
        holder.price.setText(contactListItems.getDbprice());
        holder.editquantity.setText(String.valueOf(contactListItems.getDbquantity()));


    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.editquantity.getText().toString());
            prc = Integer.parseInt(holder.price.getText().toString());
           /* if (qty == 0) {

            } else {*/

                qty = qty + 1;

                holder.editquantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));

                int id = Integer.parseInt(holder.idtxt.getText().toString());

                SqlHandler db = new SqlHandler(context);

                String query = "UPDATE SERVICES_LIST SET quantity = "+String.valueOf(qty)+" WHERE id= "+id+"" ;

                Toast.makeText(context," "+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                db.executeQuery(query);

            Services i = new Services();


            if (i.totalprice.getText().toString().length()>0){

                 prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_ORDER_LIST, context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                int u = prefs.getInt("totalsp", 0);

                totalpricestr = prc+u;

            }else{

                totalpricestr = totalpricestr+Integer.parseInt(holder.price.getText().toString());

            }

            i.totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(totalpricestr));

             prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_ORDER_LIST, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            editor.putInt("totalsp", totalpricestr);
            editor.commit();


        }
    });

    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.editquantity.getText().toString());
            prc = Integer.parseInt(holder.price.getText().toString());

            if (qty == 0) {

            } else {

                qty = qty - 1;

                holder.editquantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));

                int id = Integer.parseInt(holder.idtxt.getText().toString());

                SqlHandler db = new SqlHandler(context);

                String query = "UPDATE SERVICES_LIST SET quantity = "+String.valueOf(qty)+" WHERE id= "+String.valueOf(id)+"" ;

                //String query = "DELETE FROM SERVICES_LIST";

                Toast.makeText(context," "+query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                db.executeQuery(query);

                Services i = new Services();

                if(Integer.valueOf(i.totalprice.getText().toString())!=0){

                    if (i.totalprice.getText().toString().length()>0){

                     prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_ORDER_LIST, context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                     int u = prefs.getInt("totalsp", 0);

                    totalpricestr = u-prc;

                }else{

                    totalpricestr = totalpricestr-Integer.parseInt(holder.price.getText().toString());

                }

                    i.totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(totalpricestr));



                    prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_ORDER_LIST, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                    editor.putInt("totalsp", totalpricestr);
                    editor.commit();

                }else{}
            }
        }
    });



    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView idtxt;
    public TextView service;
    public TextView price;
    public TextView editquantity;
    public Button plus;
    public Button minus;
}
```

Now my problem is that when i click on  holder.plus button my edittext value is incremented by 1 and holder.minus button it is decremented but when i SCROLL values are getting back to previous values they are getting recycled.

I dont want my rows to be recycled or if recycled how to retain values.
I have declared my listview in a FRAGMENT

and written a method to display data from sqlite DB into listview

```
    public void showList() {

            ArrayList<ServiceListItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ServiceListItems>();
            contactList.clear();

            String query = null;



                query = "SELECT * FROM SERVICES_LIST WHERE category = 'QA'";


      Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
            if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) ;
            {
                if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        ServiceListItems contactListItems = new ServiceListItems();

                        contactListItems.setDbid(c1.getInt(c1
                                .getColumnIndex("id")));
                        contactListItems.setDbname(c1.getString(c1
                                .getColumnIndex("name")));
                        contactListItems.setDbprice(c1.getString(c1
                                .getColumnIndex("price")));
                        contactListItems.setDbquantity(c1.getInt(c1
                                .getColumnIndex("quantity")));

                        contactList.add(contactListItems);

                    } while (c1.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            c1.close();

            ServicesListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ServicesListAdapter(
                    getContext(), contactList);
            list.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);
}
```

As i have written this Fragment class i am not able to run this method from my baseadapter which i have shown.

When i use this method

```
Fragment o = new Fragment();

o.showlist(); // show list is not being detected
```

will there be any method to to run method in fragment from baseadapter.

My xml File for servicerow (declared in baseadapter)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:weightSum="10"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#E6E6E6">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/idtxt"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/producttxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Product"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/pricetxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/plusbtn"
                        android:layout_width="12dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        android:text="+"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editquantity"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="0" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/minusbtn"
                        android:layout_width="12dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks every one for you suggestion i tried a different approach and problem solved.

Comment: Put your .xml file here!!

Comment: after `holder.editquantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));`
 just add `contactListItems.setDbquantity(qty)` you need to update the model while updating item quantity
and similarly update the price or anything which is updated.

Comment: if i add contactListItems.setDbquantity(qty)     it is setting 0 as it is initial value when ii refresh page it is showing exact value saved in sqlite database i.e, if incre,ented once 1 ,2,3 so on

Comment: then why are you updating database on each increments or decrements Just update database when all data is submitted

Comment: all are different rows and need to be updated individually at a time cant be updated.

Comment: also can look at my cursor declared in showlist() how to run that in baseadapter to update data as you have said @ Vishal Patoliya

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i think this will help you. Create a HashMap of integer(key) & string(value) before you set your adapter. Something like:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> itemsMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

now, whenever you click the holder.plus button or holder.minus button, make entries for the position in the map, like below:

```
itemsMap.put(position, qty);
```

after changing the quantities ofcourse. Then finally, in your getView() method, check if the map is not null and value at that position is not null. If value exists at that position, then simply set text at that position.

```
if (itemsMap != null && itemsMap.get(position) != null) {
                holder.editquantity.setText.setText(itemsMap.get(rowId));
            }
```

Try this, i hope this helps. Happy coding...

Comment: actually i am saving data directly in sqlitedb every time because i am having 10  fragments with same listview so i think using HashMap for all views may not be easy

Comment: @RameshK, ok... i did not know this. Let me think of an alternate approach in that case. Do all your fragments share the same data? Do you show data in all fragments using the same table?

Comment: all the data will be similar but based on categories it will be divided based on fragment name everything is clear but only problem is when listview is scrolled data is losing

Comment: how to retain edittext value in  listview on scroll @vibhor_shri thanks for your concern